# Pyramid: extend query string for every URL constructed by route_url

Tags: python, web-applications, url-routing, pyramid

I'm using the Webframework Pyramid and URL Dispatch where I defined a lot of Routes like

```
config.add_route('login', '/login')
config.add_route('logout', '/logout')
```

Now I want to append something to the query string, such that URLs that are constructed by

```
request.route_url('login')
```

are actually

```
/login?foo=bar
```

This should be done on a project basis to avoid writing

```
request.route_url('login', _query={'foo': 'bar'})
```

everytime I want to construct an URL.

What is the right place to do this? Should I somehow inherit from the pyramid.request class and overwrite the route_url method? Is there an event or hook that I can use?

Comment: What's so wrong with `request.route_url('login', _query={'foo': 'bar'})`? With your description I can't suggest what's the problem. Do you wanna get `/login?foo=bar` when calling `request.route_url('login')`?

Comment: no, I want to get /login?foo=bar in *every* call of route_url without inserting the kwarg _query everytime I call route_url. Of course this is only because of sourcecode-aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Like I said. When calling `request.route_url('login')` you want to get `/login?foo=bar`. Or do you mean when calling `request.route_url()` without any parameter you want to get `/login?foo=bar`? In both cases I would inherit from `pyramid.request.Request`, override the `route_url()`-method and call [`config.set_request_factory`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.set_request_factory) at startup.

Comment: `request.route_url('login')` should yield `/login?foo=bar` and so on (for every route). I'll do how you suggested and inherit from `Request` and post this solution as an answer, when it's done.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a pregenerator and assign it to your routes.

```
def add_query_pregen(request, elements, kwargs):
    query = kwargs.setdefault('_query', {})
    query.setdefault('foo', 'bar')
    return elements, kwargs

def add_route_with_query(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['pregenerator'] = add_query_pregen
    config.add_route(*args, **kwargs)

add_route_with_query('login', '/login')
add_route_with_query('logout', '/logout')
```

Basically the pregenerator is invoked anytime you call `request.route_url` and the like and is passed the elements and kwargs, allowing you to mutate them before the url is actually generated.

Comment: I didn't know about `pregenrator`s yet. The thing with your suggestion is that it makes the code less reusable since I need to change every call to `add_route` into `add_route_with_query` in the `__init__`. It would be preferable for me to only add some files to the project or only change one single file. So I'll try to implement @floqqi s suggestion from his comment and post it as an answer as well.

Comment: It's actually way *more* reusable because you can still have routes in your system that do not have the pregenerator. You may think you don't need that now but in my experience that typically turns out to be short-sighted. Subclassing and overriding Pyramid's one way of generating urls is a global operation and you better be sure you mean it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion on this site, I implemented the following solution:

```
from pyramid.request import Request as OldRequest

class Request(OldRequest):
    def route_url(self, route_name, *elements, **kw):
        qs = kw.get('_query', {})
        if 'hid' in qs: raise Exception('hid exists in query string')
        qs['hid'] = 1337
        kw['_query'] = qs
        return self.route_without_hid(route_name, *elements, **kw)

    def route_url_without_hid(self, route_name, *elements, **kw):
        return super(Request, self).route_url(route_name, *elements, **kw)
```

and it also leaves the possibility to construct URLs that do not have an hid.

Comment: I have one more question: at the moment I do `config = Configurator(request_factory=Request)` in the `__init__` function. Is there a way to it in decorator style?